# Pinterest generated token life time

Tags: pinterest

On the page https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/access_token/ you can generate an access token. Does anyone know what the lifetime of that token is? Does it expire after fixed time?

Regards

Ismail

Comment: There is currently no default expiration period, meaning they will last forever. That will likely change in the near future, and applied to existing tokens. But for now, they are invincible!

Comment: good question, also interested in answer...

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no default expiration period, meaning they will last forever. That will likely change in the near future, and applied to existing tokens. But for now, they are invincible!